# RealityKit – Moving an entity in a racing game

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, realitykit

I was wondering if someone could help me with a question. I’m making a racing game using RealityKit, but I really don’t know how could I move my car like a real car (pressing the accelerator would make the car gradually move and if I let it go, the car would de-accelerate) and how to make the car turn while moving.

I’m kind of new to iOS dev. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that might have the same problem. I opened a ticked for Apple (I have the paid developer account) and it turns out, as of now (april 2020), it is not possible to do such thing. Only using SCNVehiclePhysics from SceneKit.